# How I can change the background color in QTableWidget()?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

Currently I have this code:

```
self.tblDinamic = QTableWidget()
self.tblDinamic.setFont(font)
```

And I want to set/change the default blank/white color of these background.
I don't know if I can change it in general (in the own `QTableWidget()` ) or I should change it in his `QTableWidgetItem()`. But if I can, I prefer change it on `QTableWidget()`

Anyone could help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same question, I have found the answer :

as said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18889015/how-to-change-qtablewidgets-spesific-cells-backround-color-in-pyqt) :

*You must first create an item in that place in the table before you can set its background color.*

```
self.tableWidget.setItem(3, 5, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem())
self.tableWidget.item(3, 5).setBackground(QtGui.QColor(100,100,150))
```

other good [example](http://codeprogress.com/python/libraries/pyqt/showPyQTExample.php?key=QTableWidgetBackgroundImage&index=436) using image

Comment: Thank you so much, I had not seen the whole post and I've watched it if it was created before hehehe